# Azure managed application defintion and terraform scripts

Tags: azure, user-interface, terraform, azure-resource-manager, managed

Is it possible to create an "azure managed application definition" using createUIDefintion.json file and terraform scripts, instead of a mainTemplate.json (arm template) ?.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible because to create and publish a managed application definition you would need a **zip file** which should contain the *mainTemplate.json* and *createUiDefinition.json* files.

If you check this [Create and publish a managed application definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/managed-applications/publish-service-catalog-app?tabs=azure-powershell) document then you will find -

> Every managed application definition includes a file named *mainTemplate.json*. In it, you define the Azure resources to deploy. The template is no different than a regular ARM template.

and

> You define the portal experience for creating the managed application. The *createUiDefinition.json* file generates the portal interface. You define how users provide input for each parameter.

Then we package the files by adding the two files to a *.zip* file. And the two files must be at the root level of the *.zip* file. If you put them in a folder, you receive an error when creating the managed application definition.

After setting authorization rules, now you can create the  managed application definition using terraform  as shown below.

```json
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_managed_application_definition" "example" {
  name                = "example-managedapplicationdefinition"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  lock_level          = "ReadOnly"
  package_file_uri    = "Path of the zip file...."
  display_name        = "TestManagedApplicationDefinition"
  description         = "Test Managed Application Definition"

  authorization {
    service_principal_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
    role_definition_id   = "a094b430-dad3-424d-ae58-13f72fd72591"
  }
}
```

For more information read these [Create and publish a managed application definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/managed-applications/publish-service-catalog-app?tabs=azure-powershell#create-the-managed-application-definition) and  [azurerm_managed_application_definition](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/managed_application_definition) document from terraform.